# How can I model this kind of thing?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi, Im newbie at blender 3d.

I just saw this at motion graphic, but don't understand how to model this shape.

Can I get any advise for modeling this shape?

Comment: HI. What specifically about the shape is the problem? The hexagon alignment or the wrapping around the sphere? What have you tried and what *specific* problem did you come up against?

Comment: Hi, speicically about wrapping around the sphere. modeling hexagon is no problem. just want to know wrapping aroung sphere with using proper mask.