# How to model a globe with an elevated honeycomb pattern?

Tags: modeling, mesh, panel

My English is not good and We don't have lots of Blender tutorial or lesson. I write this question in this site.

I am wondering how to make paneling model in blender

[image]

this is a continent model on surface.

i try to make this with particle system. but the particle system is overlap each hexagonal module and contol density hard.

there is no volume select modifier like 3ds max in blender?
and better scattter (paneling) solution in blender?

Answer for me~~Thanks~

Comment: Is this the same question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/how-can-i-model-this-kind-of-thing

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to parent the hexagon to an icsophere and to enable the face duplication of the icosphere : the hexagon will be copied on each faces of the icosphere. Then, you just have to delete all faces which are in the ocean. You will need a second icosphere to modelize oceans.

- create a new project and delete the cube object
- Add a first icosphere (<kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select *Icosphere*) to modelize continents
- in the tool property panel, change *Subdivision* to 5
- Duplicate the icosphere object (to modelize oceans)
- create a cylinder (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>) + <kbd>A</kbd> and select "*Cylinder*")
- in the tool property panel, change *Vertices* to 6 (to have an hexagon)
- change the *Radius* to 0.02
- change the *Depth* to O.05
- Change the *Cap fill type* to nothing
- Add a *Solidify* modifier and click the *Apply* button
- select the hexagon and then the first icosphere, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and click *Set parent to Object*
- select the first icosphere
- in the object panel, press the *Faces* button in the *Duplication* pane
- edit the first sphere and delete faces which are in the ocean

Answer (score 0):

I would make a 2D, black and white hexagon map, then use it in a material/texture to modify the normal (this is called [bump mapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/bump_and_normal.html)). If you're using the Cycles rendering engine, see [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html).